# Does Oracle execute all overdue jobs when changing job_queue_processes from 0 to another value?

Tags: oracle

`job_queue_processes` has been disabled for three days. When we enable it, it will execute all overdue jobs immediately or according to the job's scheduled time? or maybe we need to manually run all the jobs?

Should we change this parameter is a non-production hour because it may execute all overdue jobs immediately?

Comment: Jon processing was disabled; there are no "overdue" jobs. Jobs should resume on their normal schedule.

Comment: It will execute overdue jobs, unless you have windowing defined that puts them out of their appropriate run window. Most jobs however don't have this, and if the job slaves start up and find non-running jobs with a next start date in the past, it will run them immediately. The schedule (interval) only takes effect when a job is run to calculate the *next* start time.